# ¿Cómo puedo obtener la lista de datas de un package y que puedan ser utilizados en un bucle for?

Tags: r, rstudio

Me gustaría obtener una lista de de datas que formen parte de un package para que puedan ser utilizados en un bucle for, por ejemplo tengo el package:

```
data_package <- data(package ='datasets')

Data sets in package ‘datasets’:

AirPassengers             Monthly Airline Passenger Numbers 1949-1960
BJsales                   Sales Data with Leading Indicator
BJsales.lead (BJsales)    Sales Data with Leading Indicator
BOD                       Biochemical Oxygen Demand
CO2                       Carbon Dioxide Uptake in Grass Plants
ChickWeight               Weight versus age of chicks on different diets
DNase                     Elisa assay of DNase
EuStockMarkets            Daily Closing Prices of Major European Stock
                          Indices, 1991-1998
```

y quiero obtener las datas de tal forma que puedan ser utilizados en un bucle for, por ejemplo estaba intentando de esta forma:

```
data_package <- data(package ='datasets')

for (i in data_package){
sum(i) 
}
```

El sum es una función cualquiera utilizada en el ejemplo pero se debe mencionar que todas las datas del package que estoy utilizando tiene las mismas columnas:

```
Pacientes Sexo Medida
```

Entonces, quisiera aplicar la misma función a cada una de las datas que se encuentran dentro del paquete.

Gracias por la información.

Answer (score 3):

Con el ejemplo del paquete `dataset`.

Con la siguiente sintaxis se obtiene la lista de data sets del paquete.

```
sd<-data(package = "datasets")
```

El objeto `sd` es una lista que en objeto `results` guarda los nombres de los data set.

Entonces, si quieres aplicar una función a cada uno de los data set con un `for`, sería así. Voy aplicar la función `lenght()`

```
for (i in 1:104) {
  print(length(get(gsub(" .*","",sd[["results"]][,3][i]))))
}
```

Que arroja...

```
[1] 144
[1] 32
[1] 3
[1] 19
[1] 5307
[1] 3
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 3
[1] 3
[1] 2
[1] 84
[1] 98
...
```

Primero, que nada estoy usando la función `gsub()` para eliminar los caracteres que están después del nombre de los dataframe, es probable que para tu ejemplo no sea necesario, así que puedes omitirlo y te quedaría así:

```
for (i in 1:104) {
  print(length(get(sd[["results"]][,3][i])))
}
```

La función `get()` retorna el valor de los objetos cuando se le brinda el nombre de los objetos. Ahora porque el `for` va desde 1 a 104, porque ese es el número de data set que tiene este paquete.

Comment: Me sale este error cuando aplico mi función, no se como solucionarlo

`Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : cannot open the connection`

Comment: Olvide mencionar que mi función tiene este la función  `write.csv`

Comment: No te entiendo muy bien, puedes explicar un poco màs a detalle?

Comment: Esta es la función que le aplico a mi paquete de datos:

`stats <- function(x){
y= x %>% pivot_longer(!c(bcr_patient_barcode), names_to = "var1", values_to = "Var2"
x_name <- deparse(substitute(x))
Nombre <- paste0(x_name, "_stats.csv")
write.csv(datos, Nombre)
}`

aqui va el bucle for:
`sd<-data(package = "datasets")
for (i in 1:104) {
  stats(get(gsub(" .*","",sd[["results"]][,3][i])))
}`

Si es necesario usar el `gsubb`

Comment: y me sale el error mencionado anteriormente, pero creería que eso me sale por el comando write que uso al final de mi función

Answer (score 1):

Si te sirve, esta función recupera los datasets de un paquete, carga el paquete y carga los datos en una lista que termina retornando:

```
get_data_from_package <- function(package) {
  datas <- data(package=package, envir=new.env())$results[,"Item"]
  datas <- sapply(strsplit(datas, split=" ", fixed=TRUE), "[", 1)
  if (length(datas)>0) {
    library(package,character.only = TRUE)
    lst <- lapply(datas, get)
    names(lst) <- datas
    detach(paste("package", package, sep = ":"), unload = TRUE, character.only = TRUE)
    return(lst)
  }
  return(list())
}
```

Por ejemplo, si quieres los datos de `ggplot2`:

```
lista <- get_data_from_package("ggplot2")
sapply(lista, nrow)

      diamonds      economics economics_long      faithfuld    luv_colours        midwest            mpg 
         53940            574           2870           5625            657            437            234 
        msleep   presidential          seals      txhousing 
            83             11           1155           8602
```

Comment: Si funciona para tomar los datasets del package que tengo, para aplicar estos datasets en un bucle for debería aplicar lo siguiente: 

`for (i in lista2) {
  length(i)
}`

O estoy equivocado

Comment: quiero que me vaya tomando cada data y le aplique la función

Comment: @HenrySebastianRocanoDomingu, efectivamente, así es como debería procesar la lista.